# Testing Dropwizard 'Application' class

Tags: java, dropwizard

I'm looking to test the Dropwizard 'Application' class without bootstrapping an entire Dropwizard server.

I'd essentially just like to ensure that the one bundle I'm registering is registered successfully.

All the routes I've been down so far result in NullPointer exceptions due to various other components not being setup correctly. Is there an easy path here?

```
public class SentimentApplication extends Application<SentimentConfiguration> {

    public static void main(final String[] args) throws Exception {
        new SentimentApplication().run(args);
    }

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return "Sentiment";
    }

    @Override
    public void initialize(final Bootstrap<SentimentConfiguration> bootstrap) {
        bootstrap.setConfigurationSourceProvider(
            new SubstitutingSourceProvider(bootstrap.getConfigurationSourceProvider(),
                    new EnvironmentVariableSubstitutor(false)
            )
        );
    }

    @Override
    public void run(final SentimentConfiguration configuration,
                    final Environment environment) {
        // TODO: implement application
    }

}
```

Comment: what code produces NPE and could you share the stack trace as well please.

Answer (score 0):

You can register a simple command and call `run` method of your application with that command instead of server command. That way your application will be executed without running a server.

I wanted to do sth similar to what you want. (Considering `ExampleApp` as main `Application` class of my code) I wanted to write a test to make sure that there is no exception parsing the configuration. (Because `KotlinModule()` should have beed registered to `environment.objectMaooer` in `initialize` method of app, otherwise we would have had a runtime error.) I achieved it with sth similar to:

```kotlin
import io.dropwizard.cli.EnvironmentCommand
import io.dropwizard.setup.Bootstrap
import io.dropwizard.setup.Environment
import com.example.config.ExampleConfiguration
import net.sourceforge.argparse4j.inf.Namespace
import org.junit.Test
import kotlin.test.assertEquals
import kotlin.test.assertNotNull

class DummyCommand(app: DummyApp) : EnvironmentCommand<ExampleConfiguration>(app, "dummy", "sample test cmd") {
    var parsedConfig: ExampleConfiguration? = null

    override fun run(environment: Environment, namespace: Namespace, configuration: ExampleConfiguration) {
        parsedConfig = configuration
    }
}

class DummyApp : ExampleApp() {
    val cmd: DummyCommand by lazy { DummyCommand(this) }

    override fun initialize(bootstrap: Bootstrap<ExampleConfiguration>) {
        super.initialize(bootstrap)
        bootstrap.addCommand(cmd)
    }
}

class ExampleAppTest {
    @Test
    fun `Test ExampleConfiguration is parsed successfully`() {
        val app = DummyApp()
        app.run("dummy", javaClass.getResource("/example-app-test/test-config.yml").file)
        val config = app.cmd.parsedConfig
        assertNotNull(config)
        assertEquals("foo", config.nginxUsername)
    }
}
```